# terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Tags: swift, segue

I keep getting error when I press on a button to move me to different segue. I did the check if the Button has yellow flag but it didn't have anything.

[This is the Error keep getting after I clicked the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQCA4.png)

Comment: It tells you the error right on there, except you need to read it.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the text that you put in your image.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should read the error log properly see the 3 lines above **First throw call stack** you will clearly understand what is the problem , If not give more details of storyboard segue the way you have used it

Comment: i am new to xcode and i really appreciate your time for pointing the problem. Thank you